# Run command at boot up Solaris

Tags: solaris

I am trying to run the following at boot time ...

`/usr/openwin/bin/xset -b`

so I created the following shell script

```
  #! /bin/sh

  case $1 in
  'start')

   /usr/openwin/bin/xset -b
  ;;
  'stop')
  ;;

  *)
  echo "Usage : $0 start|stop" >&2
  exit 1
  ;;
  esac
  exit 0
```

Placed it init.d and set the following ...

`ln -s /etc/init.d/nobeep /etc/rc3.d/S100nobeep`

Is this the correct way to try and achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues, first `S100something` is really `S10something` as rc scripts are in form `[KS][0-9][0-9]*` and run in ascii order. If you want a script to be run at the end of the boot process, call it `S99something`, or better, use a `smf` service.

The second issue is `xset` is an X11 command that must be run with a valid `DISPLAY` variable or `-display` option, which is not the case when init scripts are run.

You should then launch this command in your own profile script. Which file precisely depends on what Solaris release and which shell you use.